# Codeigniter word limiter closing html tag

Tags: php, codeigniter

Hello stackoverflow community!
I'm using default word limiter in CI. But the trouble is, that it doesnt close html tags and if 1 news ended on strong tag - whole page under this becomes strong.
I looked at CI wiki page at github, but if i use that solution, '...' changed place and stay not after limited text, but after not limited h2. 
html code:

```
<h2><?=$item['title'];?></h2>           
<?word_limiter($item['text'],25);?>
```

$item['text'] is in p tags already, because of typing that in crud admin panel. 
When i used approach from CI wiki page, it looked like this (already on loaded page)

```
<h2>News</h2> "..."
<p>There is some news i wanna te</p>
```

I hope anyway would find that question useful aswell.  Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First, you need to remove HTML tags from the string with [`strip_tags()`](http://php.net/strip_tags) function, then you can use [`word_limiter()`](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/helpers/text_helper.html) helper function safely:

```
echo word_limiter(strip_tags($item['text']), 25);
```

Comment: Great Answer sir. I have done it like `strip_tags(word_limiter($item['text'], 25));` this but your suggested code is the correct. Thanks